AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' this error is persisting python plspm package
I tried to run plsSEM in collab but this error is showing. I saw an YouTuber run the same code successfully, so I think there is some problem with pandas. Can anyone help me out?
I was expecting SEM table
But the error is:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'


DataFrame.map is a new function introduced in pandas 2.1.0, if you have an older version you should use DataFrame.applymap.
To solve your issue, either modify the code to use applymap, or probably better since this is a third party library, update pandas to a recent version.
Open a shell and run:
pip install -U pandas

NB. plspm-python has a requirements.txt file, but it doesn't specify minimal versions to use:
pandas
numpy
scipy
statsmodels
scikit-learn
pytest
setuptools
wheel
twine
sphinx
m2r

The developers seem aware of the deprecation of applymap since it was explicitly mentioned in this commit.

applymap was replaced with map as applymap is deprecated

You could open a new issue suggesting to require pandas 2.1.0 as a minimal version:
pandas >= 2.1.0

